# VB.NET VisualStyleRenderer not working at all

Tags: vb.net, visual-styles

Does anybody see my mistake here?

```
Private Sub Form1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    Dim renderer As VisualStyleRenderer
    renderer = New VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Normal)

    Dim nRect As New Rectangle
    nRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(0, 0, 100, 100)

    renderer.DrawBackground(Me.PictureBox1.CreateGraphics, nRect)
    Me.PictureBox1.Invalidate(True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never draw on `CreateGraphics()`; it will be erased next time the control paints itself.

Instead, you need to handle the `Paint` event and draw on `e.Graphics`.

Comment: Thank you! And how would I draw into the PictureBox's persistent DC? Or is a persistent DC only an illusion that VB6 gave me?